# htaccess: Redirect www.domain.com/value1/value2 to path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect (301) the URL:

```
http://domain.com/eintrag/THIS-IS-DYNAMIC
```

to

```
http://domain.com/to/an/other/file.php?url=THIS-IS-DYNAMIC
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^eintrag/(.*)/$ http://domain.com/to/an/other/file.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

You'll need a `RewriteRule`. In this case `(*.)` is a regex capture which will take the place of `$1` in the resulting URL. The `1` in `$1` is for first capturing group. You can have multiple capturing groups.

so, `http://domain.com/eintrag/something_here/` will redirect to `http://domain.com/to/an/other/file.php?url=something_here`

Please make sure to modify the regex to suit your specific scenario.
I haven't tested it. But, I hope it helps.